# Question about the the velocity and acceleration in tensor notation

Tags: general-relativity, kinematics, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, covariance

When computing the volicty of a particle moving along a curve parametrized by $Z^i(t)$ for each component i, the components of the velocity $V^i$ are given by $$V^i = (d/dt)Z^i$$ and the components fo the acceleration are given by $$A^i=(d/dt)V^i + \Gamma^i_{jk} V^j V^k.$$

My question is:  why the derivative of the basis vectors doesn't appear in the expression for the velocity? Because the for the Christoffel symbol to appear in the acceleration expression there has to be a derivative in respect to the basis vectors. What am I missing here? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It's because velocity and acceleration are vectors, but the position is not, it's a scalar. There is no need to differentiate basic vectors if you're just differentiating a scalar.

Comment: But how the Christoffel symbol appear then?

Comment: It appears in the expression for the acceleration because velocity is a vector.

Comment: I don't understand your reasoning, because position is a vector too, and velocity is the derivative of the position vector with respect to time.

Comment: In general, position is not a vector; a position is a point.

Comment: But doesn't it make sense to me. From what you are saying when you act with the derivative, in one case you ignore the basis vectors, in the other you consider and hence differenciate them.

Comment: "Any help": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_acceleration#In_curved_spacetime (also scroll up). "More help": 

Comment: Think this is the gist of it: $Z(t)$ gives points for times, $d_tZ(t)|_T$ gives direction of Z at time T, and $d_t d_t Z(t)$ is a function of the direction at two different points (the christoffel symbols maps the velocity vector basis in one tangent space to another). The basis for points is only isomorphic/same as basis for vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$, or something like that.

Comment: This page is where I kind of understood what the connection was about https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_connection

Answer (score 1):

Definition of directional covariant derivative
The directional covariant derivative of a vector along a curve in a manifold is defined as
$D/d\sigma P^\mu$
where:
$D/d$ directional covariant derivative
$\gamma (\sigma)$ curve
$\sigma$ proper time (massive particle) or affine parameter (massless particle, e.g. photon)
$\mu = 0, 1, 2, 3$
$P^\mu$ vector
If $x^\mu(\sigma)$ describes the curve, it may be written as
$D/d\sigma P^\mu = \dot x^\nu \nabla_\nu P^\mu$ (1)
where:
$\dot x^\mu = dx^\mu/d\sigma$
$\nabla_\mu$ covariant derivative
In case of a vector, you have
$\nabla_\nu P^\mu = \partial_\nu P^\mu + \Gamma^\mu_{\nu \lambda} P^\lambda$

Velocity
If the vector represents the position, that is $P^\mu = x^\mu$, (1) measures the velocity $V^\mu$ of the particle
$V^\mu =  D/d\sigma x^\mu = \dot x^\nu \nabla_\nu x^\mu = \dot x^\nu \partial_\nu x^\mu + \dot x^\nu \Gamma^\mu_{\nu \lambda} x^\lambda$ (2)

Acceleration
As for the acceleration $A^\mu$ you apply the (1) once again to the velocity $V^\mu$ in (2)
$A^\mu = D/d\sigma V^\mu = \dot x^\nu \nabla_\nu V^\mu$

Note
The covariant derivative already embeds the change of the basis vectors along a curve in a manifold to describe correctly the change of the geometric object. This is accounted for by the connection $\Gamma$.
The formulas in the question do not seem correct.

Answer (score 0):

“When computing the velocity of a particle moving along a curve“ I think perhaps the confusion arises from the ambiguity in the question: is the velocity of the particle itself is moving along the given curve or is the curve represents particle’s velocity (representing the change in its position ) ; does Z represent a scalar field or a vector field?